# Symfony 4.3 - Cannot autowire service argument that references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security"

Tags: symfony, security, service

I'm using Symfony 4.3.

I have a problem with autowiring service argument in controller method.
It seems like Security class cannot be found.

I installed Security component by `composer require symfony/security`

This is row from "composer show":

`symfony/security                    v4.3.4  Symfony Security Component`

Composer.json:

`"symfony/security": "4.3.*",`

Services.yaml:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

HomeController.php:

```
use App\Service\DB\DBALProvider;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index(DBALProvider $DBALProvider)
    {
```

DBALProvider.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class DBALProvider
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $context;
    private $user;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Security $security)
    {
```

Error that displays when I enter "/" route

```
Cannot resolve argument $DBALProvider of "App\Controller\HomeController::index()": Cannot autowire service "App\Service\DB\DBALProvider": argument "$security" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security" but no such service exists.
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you get when you run `php bin/console debug:autowiring` in your terminal?

Comment: Use  "composer require symfony/security-bundle" to install the security bundle which defines the Security service. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `composer require symfony/security-bundle`

is the solution (thanks to [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad)).

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Well I though that `composer require symfony/security` install all necessary bundles.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  symfony/security just loads the low level security component (aka library).  There are plenty of non Symfony framework projects out there that use the component.  The bundle code is just a Symfony specific wrapper mostly for configuring the security components.  You will see this component/bundle pattern used quite a bit in the framework.